# Avoiding race conditions in Kotlin, Smartcast is impossible runtime exception

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

The line:

> viewAdapter.setTitleData(bezinningModels)

in the below snippet is giving me the runtime warning:

> Smart cast to 'BezinningAdapter' is impossible, because 'viewAdapter'
>   is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time

I went through a lot of posts with a similar runtime warning, and I understood why this happens. Basically Kotlin wants to avoid race conditions so that the value of a mutable object could not change,but still I do not get what I should do to avoid this mistake so that I can call the retrofit call into the `RecyclerView Array`
I tried to change from `var` to `val` the value of `RecyclerView` but did not work

Here the snippet that causes the problem:

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
class MainFragment : android.app.Fragment() {




private lateinit var viewManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager
private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView

private lateinit var viewAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<*>

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    val view = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.bezinning_fragment, container, false)

   viewManager=LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    viewAdapter=BezinningAdapter()

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view) as RecyclerView
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
    recyclerView.layoutManager=viewManager
    recyclerView.adapter=viewAdapter


    val subscribe = bezinningListViewModel!!.showBezinningLijst("132")
            ?.subscribeOn(schedulerProvider!!.io())
            ?.observeOn(schedulerProvider!!.ui())
            ?.subscribe(object : FlowableSubscriber<List<BezinningModel>> {
                override fun onError(t: Throwable?) {
                    Log.d("IVO", "onError: ")
                }

                override fun onComplete() {
                    Log.d("IVO", "onComplete: ")
                }

                override fun onSubscribe(s: Subscription) {
                    s.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);

                }

                override fun onNext(bezinningModels: List<BezinningModel>?) 
   {

                    val JSONResponseBody = bezinningModels!! 
[0].attribute.body
                    viewAdapter.setTitleData(bezinningModels)


                    val bodyBezinningParsedHtml = 
Html.fromHtml(JSONResponseBody)



                }


            })

    return view

}



}
```

Comment: you can also always smart-cast local variables. so something like `val viewAdapter = BezziningAdapter(); viewAdapter.whatever(); /*...*/ this.viewAdapter = viewAdapter` would work _in the general case_, since a `val` stack variable will never change value

Comment: I see thanks @Groostav,makes sense because `val` is like a `final` in java i guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that `viewAdapter` is going to be a `BezinningAdapter`, then declare it as such:

```
private lateinit var viewAdapter: BezinningAdapter<*>
```

Comment: Thanks. it is working if I do like that `private lateinit var viewAdapter: BezinningAdapter` without the diamond. So I am starting to understand, the reason why I get this Smartcast exception is the fact that I am kind of initializing it twice?

Comment: It has to be casted in general because you declared `viewAdapter` as a `RecyclerView.Adapter` at first and then assigned it to a `BezinningAdapter` later. Smartcast isn't possible here (on `var` types) because the reference could be any subtype of `RecyclerView.Adapter` at any time.